# JetBrains Pycharm - Getting error while debugging my project

Tags: python, django, django-models, pycharm

I just switched to Mac from windows.
I imported my project in pycharm from [GitHub](http://github.com/rajababu3/ecommercedjango/) but it is giving unknown errors.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10b75f6a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rajababu/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rajababu/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/rajababu/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/rajababu/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/rajababu/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rajababu/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/rajababu/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/rajababu/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Users/rajababu/anaconda/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import_export'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `import_export` is not in your INSTALLED_APPS.

Install `import_export` with pip

```
pip install django-import-export
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `import_export` plugin. You can do this in PyCharm using File > Settings > Project Interpreter and press the "+" icon (search for it and install it). Make sure to add `import_export` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` variable in your settings as well.